# Repo.stream as Flow's infinite data source

Tags: elixir, genstage

I have been playing with Elixir `Flow` for some time now and recently I was trying to parallelize my workflow using `Flow` and `Repo.stream` using:

```
endless_db_stream = MyRepo.stream(some_query)
MyRepo.transaction(fn ->
  endless_db_stream
  |> Flow.from_enumerable()
  |> Flow.each(&process(&1))
  |> Flow.run
end)
```

but it just doesn't work. Now I have did some research and stumble into this [comment](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/issues/150#issuecomment-282996350) from Jose Valim saying basically `Repo.stream` aren't really compatible with `GenStage` and I believe its also not compatible with `Flow` (since its built atop of `GenStage`).

My question is, has anyone use PSQL as the unbounded data source for `Flow` before?

P/S: In the same GitHub thread above there is a "hack" that uses a `GenStage` to wrap the `Repo.stream` then act as a producer, but I was looking for a more streamlined approach as I was planning to use `Flow` instead of `GenStage`

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work that easily, would've been my first instinct to use Flow.from_enumerable as well but for the reason specified in the GitHub Repo, it doesn't work. It was suggested that ecto and the adapters should support Flow directly, so you'd call `MyRepo.flow()` and immediately have a flow you can work with.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to implement it in our projects.

1. the simpler way: use resources ids as the data source.

   You can list all resources ids first, then get every resource separately in flow.
2. the normal way: use `Stream.resource/3` to customize the data source.

   You can also make a stream by `Stream.resource/3`, use a paginated query to get some resources at once.

see more detail here, [How to build Streams in Elixir easily with Stream.resource/3 Awesomeness](http://benjamintan.io/blog/2015/02/05/how-to-build-streams-in-elixir-easily-with-stream-resource-awesomeness/)